# Get HTML content of ContentBlockById("X") in ExactTarget

Tags: marketing-cloud

I am new to ExactTarget (Salesforce Marketing Cloud)
I see something like this in one my templates which was done by someone else.

```
%%=ContentBlockById("123456")=%%
```

How do I find the HTML content of this above block without actually sending out an email ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fragments like this are located in Content Builder.

If you open any item there you will see the ID as the second parameter:

[image]

Sadly, the Id parameter is not searchable in the interface*, so it will not be as easy to find as one would expect.

The easiest way now (meaning: without going into programmatically finding this item) would be to:

1. Open Content Builder
2. Ignore the search field as it is useless in this case
3. Ignore the folders and remain in the top area (as indicated in the following screenshot) - this will show all content items available in this business unit

[image]

4. Use the `Sort by [ID]` option
5. Manually go through the sorted items so that you can find the ID you are searching for.
6. If there's no match when you are in the `LOCAL` Content Builder section, switch to `SHARED`

It will be tedious, but it might be the quickest way for you, if you are new to SFMC.

Comment: Thank You for your reply - yes, I was doing a search which did not yield any results. I'll check manually - thing is, there are like 100s of template sections for me to go through in various sub-folders.

Comment: @anjanesh That's why I'm recommending to use the section indicated by the arrow - it has content from all subfolders. You don't need to click all items when they are sorted by ID - for example: go to the pieces in the middle of the list, check their ID and compare with the one you are looking for and see if you need to move up or down the list. Repeat checking in the middle and you should find your piece in a few steps